# Why is my array 'undefined'? (vanilla javascript)

Tags: javascript, foreach, undefined

I'm trying to make a simple 'bad words' filter with javascript. It's meant to listen to any submit events on the page, then iterate through all input fields of the text type, check them for bad stuff by comparing the entered text with the word list, and finally return an according console.log/alert (for now).

I have two files: `word-list.js` with the critical words (loads first) and `filter.js` which pulls an array with all words from `word-list.js`.

My problems is, `swear_words_arr[1]` is '`undefined`' and I don't understand why. I've been looking around for solutions, but still I can't seem to determine the reason for this. Help is much appreciated.

```
// get all inputs type = text and turn html collection into array
var getInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")
var inputs = Array.from(getInputs);

//var swear_alert_arr -> from in word-list.js
var swear_alert_arr = new Array();
var swear_alert_count = 0;

function reset_alert_count() {
  swear_alert_count = 0;
}

function validate_text() {
  reset_alert_count();

  inputs.forEach(function(input) {

    var compare_text = input.value;

    console.log(compare_text);

      for (var i = 0; i < swear_words_arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < compare_text.length; i++) {
          if (
            swear_words_arr[i] ==
            compare_text.substring(j, j + swear_words_arr[i].length).toLowerCase()
          ) {
            swear_alert_arr[swear_alert_count] =
              compare_text.substring(
                j,
                j + swear_words_arr[i].length
              );
            swear_alert_count++;
          }
        }
      }
      var alert_text = "";

      for (var k = 1; k <= swear_alert_count; k++) {
        alert_text += "\n" + "(" + k + ")  " + swear_alert_arr[k - 1];

        if (swear_alert_count > 0) {
          alert("No!");
          console.log('omg no bad stuff! D:');
        } else {
          console.log('no bad stuff found :)');
        }
      }
    });
}

window.onload = reset_alert_count;
window.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    validate_text();
});
```

Comment: There's no sign you defining `swear_words_arr` anywhere in this code.

Comment: Agreed with @Quentin. There is no declaration for swear_words_arr, maybe you wanted to use swear_alert_arr. If not just declare your variable swear_words_arr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've declared the array you're trying to access.

But, instead of loops with nested loops and keeping track of loop counters, just get a new array that contains any bad words in the submitted array. You can do this a number of ways, but the [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method works nicely:

```js
let badWords = ["worse", "terrible", "horrible", "bad"];
let submittedWords = ["Good", "Terrible", "Great", "Fabulous", "Bad", "OK"];

// Loop over the submitted words and return an array of all the bad words found within it
let bad = submittedWords.filter(function(word){
  // Do a case-insensitive match test. Return the word from the submitted words
  // if it's on the bad word list.
  return badWords.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) > -1 ? word: null;
});

console.log("Bad words found in submitted data: " + bad.join(", "));
```

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that. Looks a lot more maintainable than my attempt.